# Finding missing numbers in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to generate a query that will produce a list of index values that are missing from a SQL table. So far, what I have is

```
SELECT index - 1
FROM table
WHERE index - 1 NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT index
    FROM table)
    AND
    index != 1;
```

This only finds the *first* missing index of a sequence of missing indices. I'd like to produce a query which outputs every number between 1 and `MAX(index)` which does not appear as an `index` in the table. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a numbers table to find the missing index values

`Recursive CTE` approach

```
DECLARE @max_num INT = (SELECT Max(index)
   FROM   table);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 AS num
         UNION ALL
         SELECT num + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  num < @max_num)
SELECT *
FROM   cte c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table t
                   WHERE  c.num = t.index)
ORDER  BY c.num
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Another approach using tally table to generate numbers.

```
;WITH E1(N)
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) tc (N)), --10E+1 or 10 rows
     E2(N)
     AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
     E4(N)
     AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
     --E5(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),  -- 10000 * 10 = 100000
     cte(NUM)
     AS (SELECT ItemNumber = Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY N) FROM E4)
SELECT *
FROM   cte c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   table t
                   WHERE  c.num = t.index)
ORDER  BY c.num
```

Currently it generates 10000 sequential row numbers an if your max value is more than 10000 then you add another cross join to increase the numbers

Comment: This is the right answer. The only thing I would do differently would be how to create the numbers table (I was gonna use a `CROSS JOIN` of `sys.all_objects` with itself and then a `ROW_NUMBER`)

Comment: @Lamak - Done bro.. but slightly different way to generate numbers

Comment: Tally table is definitely the best approach for performance. The recursive cte for counting is pretty much the same thing as a cursor. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: Now, if you change the `FROM E1 a, E1 b`  with `FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b` would be perfect

Comment: @Lamak - Thats right it is old way of doing cross join. Updated

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. The one thing I changed was that this query shows a bunch of numbers after the last one. Since I had around 30,000 indices, I did the E5 cross join, but there were still a ton of extra rows at the end. Since I was actually interested in the _number_ of results, I added `DECLARE @max_index int; SET @max_index = (SELECT MAX(index) FROM table);` to the top of the script and then made the `WHERE` clause `WHERE c.num < @max_index AND...`

Answer (score 0):

My preference for this type of query is to show ranges.  A simple way uses `lead()`:

```
select (index + 1) as first_missing, (next_index - 1) as last_missing,
       (next_index - index - 1) as num_missing
from (select t.*, lead(index) over (order by index) as next_index
      from t
     ) t
where next_index <> index + 1;
```

This shows every "internal" missing range.  Because it does not use a table of numbers, it works efficiently regardless of the size of the table or the number of missing values.

It does *not* show "missing" values at the beginning and end of the table.  Your question does not specify that as an issue.